# PowerBI Sorting numbers as text instead of numerically [SOLVED]

Tags: sorting, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

PowerBi community - help!

I have a heatmap of product failures based on product characteristics. Right now my matrix is sorting my rows incorrectly. Right now from top to bottom, it is reading 1000, 105, 110, 115, 120, 1200, 1250, 130... and I want it to be in the order of 105, 110, 115, 120, 130, 1000, 1200, 1250. I do have these values as "whole numbers" in my data table. But it seems like it is sorting them alphabetically. Thank you for any tips you have!

[Product failure heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb863.png)
[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE9wi.png)

edit: Solved - I had to unpivot my data at one point, and when I made my feild parameters I accidentally used my unpivoted data. Therefore, it was using my unpivoted data type of "text." I was able to re do my feild parameters using my original data - and this solved the issue.
[Feild parameters unpivoted -> text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwEyi.png)
[fixed heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMeu8.png)

Comment: Please describe what visual you are using for the heatmap - is it a standard visual, or custom?

Comment: Solved - I had to unpivot my data at one point, and when I made my feild parameters I accidentally used my unpivoted data. Therefore, it was using my unpivoted data type of "text." I was able to re do my feild parameters using my original data - and this solved the issue.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerBI/comments/10fdn9j/powerbi_sorting_ranking_numbers_nonnumerically/